# MP3 File Visualization

Tags: c++, mp3, data-visualization

Good day.

I aim to develop a software that can visualize the data portion of an mp3 file. I've done a good amount of internet research but I haven't found any good source. Before, I managed to create a software that can visualize uncompressed canonical wav files (8-bit, 16-bit, mono and stereo) and I want to take it further by being able to visualize mp3 files.

I know that mp3 files are not as straightforward as compared to uncompressed canonical wav files. Anyone who knows a good starting point in visualizing mp3 files is very welcome to share his or her knowledge.

I'm developing in C++.

Comment: Visualize how?  What is your question?  How to decode MP3 to raw PCM?  Or how to "visualize" audio?

Answer (score 1):

You want to decode the mp3 file to uncompressed WAV and then visualise that. Have a look at this question for some options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936177/what-is-a-good-platform-independend-c-library-for-mp3-decoding

Answer (score 0):

You may consider `LAME` to decode your input `mp3` file into raw pcm (uncompressed) and visualize it.